# Material UI , not showing up in the path of the app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material-UI component is not showing on the local host app, there is toolbar component from material-ui but it is not showing it in the browser. I have mentioned the package.json below.

I had created the app using creat-react-app. it was working before but some it is not working now.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

package.json

```
{
 "name": "reactx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.16"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Toolbar from './toolbar/toolbar';
import './app.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="/toolbar" component={ Toolbar } />
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './app';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

toolbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

export default () =>
  <AppBar position="static" color="primary">
    <Toolbar>
      <Typography type="title" color="inherit">
        My App
      </Typography>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
```

toolbar.css
`No CSS here`

Comment: do you have any errors in console?

Comment: no error is coming.